# Why is my query giving a false error when it's correct?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm using MySQL phpmyadmin with xampp V3.2.2.

and the following code won't work!

```
CREATE TABLE Car (RegPlate int(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                  Brand varchar(20) NOT NULL,
                  Color varchar(20) NOT NULL,
                  Owner int(10) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Driver(ID))
```

it gives me two errors one on `ID` which is "Unexpected begining of the statement" and another on `FOREIGN KEY`"a comma or a closing bracket is expected near `FOREIGN KEY`" but if I remove the brackets from 'ID' it's error goes away but the error on `FOREIGN KEY` still remains.Why?

But if i reconstruct my code like this it works

```
CREATE TABLE Car (RegPlate int(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                  Brand varchar(20) NOT NULL,
                  Color varchar(20) NOT NULL,
                  Owner int(10) NOT NULL,
                  FOREIGN KEY (Owner) REFERENCES driver(ID))
```

Please explain in this and in detail.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: MySQL does not permit in-line foreign key definitions.  You need the separate declaration.

Comment: Read about the syntax here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/creating-tables.html

Comment: Why ask this question. You already know how to format the statement in a way that MySQL will actually process. So format it that way

Comment: the reason is simple: mysql doesn't accept that syntax. What else are you wanting to know about it?

Comment: For the sake of your future self or other maintainers - please get in the habit of *naming* your constraints too.

Comment: Well with primary key it works why not with foreign?Also I personally like to do things inline.Is there any alternative?

Comment: I will this was only for the post

Comment: Yes, get the MySQL team to rewrite the compiler. Good luck with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [syntax for `CREATE TABLE` in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html), you'll see that the column definition has inline constraints only for `NOT NULL`, `UNIQUE`, `PRIMARY KEY`, and `DEFAULT`:

> ```
> column_definition:
>     data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT {literal | (expr)} ]
>       [AUTO_INCREMENT] [UNIQUE [KEY]] [[PRIMARY] KEY]
>       [COMMENT 'string']
>       [COLLATE collation_name]
>       [COLUMN_FORMAT {FIXED|DYNAMIC|DEFAULT}]
>       [STORAGE {DISK|MEMORY|DEFAULT}]
>       [reference_definition]
>   | data_type
>       [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (expression)
>       [VIRTUAL | STORED] [NOT NULL | NULL]
>       [UNIQUE [KEY]] [[PRIMARY] KEY]
>       [COMMENT 'string']
> ```

The traditional approach would be to use `CONSTRAINT` explicitly and give the constraint a name:

```
CREATE TABLE Car (
    RegPlate int(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Brand varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Color varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Owner int(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_car_owner FOREIGN KEY (Owner) REFERENCES driver(ID)
);
```

Comment: I'll admit it.I prefer to do things inline and without constraints but seeing that there is no other way to do it.Guess I'll have to live with it...